# Do you put builds in a source code repository?

Tags: version-control

I would like to get some feedback on this idea, as I can see the pros and cons of each approach. 
As a Java developer, this would be about storing jar files in the code repository, but it could easily extend to other compiled languages.

Pros:

- Can easily retrieve previous distributions, without the need to depend on (potientially no longer available) out of date tools to recompile.

Cons:

- Could quickly "bloat" the code repository, depending on the frequency of builds.

Comment: Yes, definitely would bloat your repository. IMO, the source repository is just that - for **source** of any kind, but **not** for the output of the builds in the end. But that's just my opinion

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We archive releases to a directory structure, and tag the appropriate versions in source control. This gives us access to the built versions and the source that generated them.

This is easily done using build scripts to automate tagging and archiving of release builds.

Comment: +1 - yup, that's what we do as well. Full release builds that passed all tests and everything are archived by our continuous integration build server on a "Release Server" into a share on disk

Comment: +1 Often, the only outputs that need to be kept are the ones which are actually released.  The others can be held onto for a few weeks, but then deleted to make room, since they can always be recreated.  Either way, outputs don't belong in source control.

Comment: +1 This makes the most sense. The source control should "in theory" be able to recreate the build but if the tools change it makes sense to have a parallel location with the actual binaries.

Comment: @Nick: This is more than just trying to keep things clean.  If you store both the output and the input, it becomes possible (hence, eventually actual) that the two don't match.  Then you wind up shipping something you can't rebuild and therefore don't know the contents of.

Answer (score 4):

Compromise: store tools and source code in repository and tag builds. This way you can always recreate any build of a product.

And you can always have a separate repository for compiled artifacts.

Comment: I think this is a good compromise. However I am also a little paranoid about older tools no longer working at some time in the future.

Comment: @Jin Kim: Assuming you also keep the releases on an FTP server or the equivalent, this should not concern you.

Answer (score 4):

If you can create a good enough build system that it is trivial to recreate an exact build with just a checkout of code, I don't believe there is any need to store your builds in the repository.

For most of my stuff I do not store specific builds of my code, but I do store specific versions of the libraries my code relies on.  I put a lot of effort in a few months ago to make it trivial to load in a tag and type "ant" and everything builds properly without relying on anything outside of the tree.  (excluding the correct javac and ant)

Unfortunately, some of our codebase does not have as good a build system (ie, requires manual setting up of sdks and grabbing various external libraries and poking environment variables) and it would be difficult to recreate exactly a specific version of a build based on the repository (we are constantly moving forward and not really supporting old code, so the developers' workstation are set up close enough that we haven't been burnt yet by having to go back to an old branch before our current release) and in that case, we do store our release's builds (for the inevitable fat finger "oh no, I was on the wrong server doing some tests" or something equally insidious).

Comment: +1.  Anything that can't be created in the build process from other inputs must itself be considered an input.  So it's ok to check in third-party libraries, or even legacy ones whose build cannot be automated.

Answer (score 3):

I store the builds on a folder in the server, and they're backed up on a regular basis. But I tag the revision which represent that build. In the build folder I store not only the executables, binaries or pages (our case is ASP.Net), but also the change scripts we get from SQL Delta.

The tags are named with the same identifier than the fields, so if you have the build "System_2009-07-30-01" you'll have a tag with that name. So if you need to fix something, you simply look at the build name, look the tag and then look the revision you need to see what may be happening.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a good reason to version the actual build.  Tag the source version and make it so that only a controlled group has access to changing the tags.  A build tag should never have a checkin done to it so it should be trivial to recreate the build.

Answer (score 1):

We go for labelling the repository for any build so we can get the actual source for any build number & then we zip and upload the actual published build files that are actually deployed - just to be sure there's no sneaky last minute config tweaks etc during deployment that areb't reflected in the trunk itself.

Answer (score 0):

Put specific customer releases in the repository.
In theory this isn't necessary since we could always reproduce that version but it's nice to be able to just get the exact .msi that was sent to a certain customer on a certain date - we then test that in a clean vm.

One reason is that it protects you against any changes outside your build environment from say Windows or visual studio update. You might not be able to reproduce a bit-bit build of an msi if msi itself has updated!

Comment: I would tend to disagree with this - I would rather know that I can build from any abitrary point an exact replica of what was sent.  Because depending on the humans involved, that .msi might not be reproducible in practice.  It might be a one-off build by some developer who forgot to check in his changes, and is hence "unsupportable."  ALWAYS rely on your build process to get it right, and if you can't, then you have something you need to fix.

Comment: Do you expect that a rebuilt MSI will differ in any way?  I don't mean functionally, but at the bit-for-bit level.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is appropriate to store build output in the version control system. Both for testing some specific version of a build and also in order to ease certain development tasks.

However, you should make sure that you'll also keep everything in the repository that would be needed to recreate that exact build if need be. You should use consitent tagging/labeling in order to facilitate this. You may need to test a bug fix with different versions of various components, and depending on the complexity of your overall system you might want to try different combinations.

Comment: I see no benefit to clogging the source control system with output.

Comment: It depends a lot on your environment and team size. In large projects with complex tooling, compiling everything from scratch just because you need some version of some component isn't always feasible. Make your own judgment.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes. Most of the time the answer is *no* but there are still scenarios where if it makes sense, do it.

As an aside, I'm surprised this is still open. These discussion type questions are usually voted closed in less than 5 minutes.

Comment: The closing nazi's must be in another time zone and still asleep.

Comment: This isn't a vague discussion of some subjective matter, it's a best practices issue.

Answer (score 0):

To mitigate the concern that old build tools may not work in newer environment, we archive our build machine images for major releases. It is easy to do for us because our build machines are virtualized. It's plan B in case other means do not work.

Answer (score -1):

I think sources, dependencies, binaries and build tools should be versioned together... This is the only way to track what is going on with the big projects where final release comes from many source projects...